# How to create a dashboard in Excel or Power BI with 12 month columns

Tags: excel, powerbi, pivot-table, visualization

I need to create a dashboard or several charts to reveal working hours. I have below excel sheet:
[image: Excel Sheet]

The whole sheet has data for all 12 months, I only show the first month here. I want to mainly show illustrate the data from the person group and the project group. So I need at least two charts, one has the filter in Person with 12 months as x-axis and total working hour as y-axis. Another one has the project as filter with same x and y axis. Both of them should also reveal the difference between planed and as-is situation in each half of every month. I think clustered bar chart should work but I donot know how to preprocess the data.

Could someone give me hint? Thank you